# Find the power-series representation for this function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, geometric-series

Here is a practice exam question we've been given (no answer provided; been scratching my head over it for a while):

[image]

Here's my work, and answer:

[image]

Could anyone verify if this is correct? And then, if possible, verify if the interval of convergence is (-1/3, 1/2)?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll know for next time.

Comment: I think it's supposed to get a series of the form $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\color{red}{x^n}$.